# Second Activity is blank

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-wrap-content

The second activity has a `ListView` and it does not display it.

The `Log.i` in the `UserList` shows that the activity is active.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public void makeUserListIntent() {
    Intent userListIntent = new 
      Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserList.class);
    startActivity(userListIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if ( ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null ) makeUserListIntent();
}
```

**UserList.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);

    Log.i("Second Activity: ", "onCreate");
    ListView listViewUserList = findViewById(R.id.listViewUserList);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("Test User");
    arrayList.add("Test User");
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new 
       ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listViewUserList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listViewUserList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**activiy_user_list.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".UserList">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewUserList"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="715dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I should see the `ListView` but a blank page appears.

The `Log.i` in the `UserList.java` shows that the activity gets called. Tried setting the `visibility` etc.

Why can't I see the `ListView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Edit The activiy_user_list.xml Like This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".UserList">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewUserList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestions were correct. ListView is showing now!

Comment: Ok. So if My answer Ws correct. check my answer right answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are setting the height to a a constant value `715dp`, hence the first few items will not be visible on smaller devices. To fix this change your height to `match_parent` and add some margin at the top if that was your desired output

Comment: This was a great answer!

Comment: If you find it useful, kindly consider checking the green tick to help future seekers